# OpenCL get_global_id

Tags: c++, c, kernel, opencl

I'm trying to port a piece of OpenCL Kernel code over to SideFX Houdini using
its internal scripting language call VEX (stand for `vector expression`).

However, Im having problem in understanding what those indexes do and how they work.
I understand that `get_global_id()`  returned the index into the work for a given work item (read it somewhere ) but I dnt really understand exactly whats that is. (perhaps something to do with the computer cores, i guess?)

SO aasuming the input is a 2D grid formed by 500pixel in x and y,
and assuming every pixel got some attributes (the one I pass into the kernel arguments, with the `name_in`, while the `name_out` are to update the same attributes value ), what is he doing with those index operation ?

How exactly is it workin and how could I do the same in `c` for example ?

Many thank you in advance,
Alessandro

```
__kernel void rd_compute(__global float4 *a_in, __global float4 *b_in, __global float4 *c_in, __global float4 *d_in, __global float4 *e_in, __global float4 *f_in, __global float4 *g_in, __global float4 *h_in, __global float4 *i_in, __global float4 *a_out, __global float4 *b_out, __global float4 *c_out, __global float4 *d_out, __global float4 *e_out, __global float4 *f_out, __global float4 *g_out, __global float4 *h_out, __global float4 *i_out)
{
    const int index_x = get_global_id(0);
    const int index_y = get_global_id(1);
    const int index_z = get_global_id(2);
    const int X = get_global_size(0);
    const int Y = get_global_size(1);
    const int Z = get_global_size(2);
    const int index_here = X*(Y*index_z + index_y) + index_x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please study many of the great introductory tutorials.

In serial code if you used a loop (e.g., `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)`) then `int i = get_global_id(0)` replaces that so you can get the *index* of the current work item. The runtime ensures that all work items are run. They might be in parallel, in serial, or in groups (some combination).

Comment: Ok will do, thank you so much for the reply, it was helpful.